# How do I get select element to look like this?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am converting a .psd to html/css. I can't find anything similar looking to this select element online to use as an example. If this even is a select element.

Comment: its created by default when you will make the input field as select in safari browser.

Comment: Looks like an IOS select.

Comment: That's an approximation of how `<select>` menus appear on macOS (not Windows), and it may have been included in the PSD for that reason. Are you sure you're required to achieve that style for all platforms?

Comment: @AniruddhaDas Thanks for letting me know. I will just ignore that part then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `appearance: none` & then style the `select` yourself. For arrows use pseudo elements `:before` & `:after`.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.select-wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  padding: 4px 20px 4px 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fcfcfc 0%,#ececec 100%);
}

.select-wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  right: 8px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid #777;
}

.select-wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  right: 8px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #777;
}

select:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-wrapper">
  <select>
    <option value="0" selected>Select Option</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!